# What does "culture" mean here?

Tags: immunology

> India becomes first country to **culture** U.K. variant strain.

[Source](https://archive.is/DvRgw)

What does "culture" mean here?

Comment: Are you asking about the exact culture conditions? (The general meaning of "culture" was given in the source: "Culture is the process by which cells are grown under controlled conditions, generally outside their natural environment.")

Answer (score 2):

Since viruses cannot reproduce outside of a cellular environment, they are cultured by infecting a living culture of host cells. In this case, it means human cells are cultured in a sterile dish and infected with a specimen of SARS-COV-2 virus, most likely collected from a patient during the early stages of infection. After infection of the cultured cells is confirmed, the new virus particles are collected from the culture media and put into storage.

Comment: Why does this need citations? This is just knowledge picked up from working in a virology/cell biology lab.